# Vimeo api to fetch videos by their uploaded date or title?

Tags: php, mysql, vimeo

How can I fetch video using Vimeo API by their their or by their uploaded date?

Currently I am using `vimeo.videos.getUploaded` to fetch all the videos of a user but I am unable to pass parameters like title or date into that method call.

So please let me know how can I fetch videos of a user by video title or by uploaded date.

Answer (score 0):

vimeo.video.getUploaded (and many other endpoints in the Vimeo API) allows you to provide a sort parameter of "oldest" or "newest".

You can experiment with this functionality via the playground : 
https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded/playground

Comment: how can I fetch video name(not the title) using the vimeo.videos.getUploaded?

Comment: Name and title are two different labels for the same data.